# Primefaces 3.4: Tree selectedNode is null

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am new in Primefaces and I try to use the Primefaces Tree for several days now.
Basically, I have a Tree. I attach to this tree a contextual menu. When I click on the contextual menu, a dialog window opens and display more details about the selected node of the tree. I try to reproduce the primefaces showcase basing on the Tree and the TreeTable example.

When I run my project, I try to open the dialog window, I have this error in the debugger:

```
WARNING: /protected/treeonly.xhtml @34,91 value="#{folderManagedBean.selectedNode.data.name}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /protected/treeonly.xhtml @34,91 value="#{folderManagedBean.selectedNode.data.name}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

Please find below the JSF Page

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form id="form">  

            <!--*********** Context Menu ***********-->
            <p:contextMenu for="folderTree">  
                <p:menuitem value="Rename Folder" update="folderPanel" oncomplete="folderDialog.show();" icon="ui-icon-plus"/>
            </p:contextMenu> 

            <!--*********** Folder Tree ***********-->
            <p:tree style="border:none;" id="folderTree" value="#{folderManagedBean.root}" var="folder" selectionMode="single" selection="#{folderManagedBean.selectedNode}">  
                <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{folder.name}" />  
                </p:treeNode>  
            </p:tree>  


            <!--*********** Dialog Box ***********-->
            <p:dialog header="New Folder" widgetVar="folderDialog" modal="true" resizable="false"  
                      showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">  
                <p:outputPanel id="folderPanel">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="4">  
                        <h:outputText value="Folder Name:" />  
                        <p:inputText value="#{folderManagedBean.selectedNode.data.name}"/> 
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>  


        </h:form>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FolderManagedBean implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private FolderBean folderBean;

    private Folder froot;  
    private TreeNode root;

    private TreeNode selectedNode;  

    public FolderManagedBean() {   
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
        root = buildTree();
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot(){
        return root;
    }


    private TreeNode buildTree(){
        froot = folderBean.getRootFolder();

        root = new DefaultTreeNode("root", null);      
        TreeNode realRoot = new DefaultTreeNode(froot, root);

        for (Folder child : froot.getChildFolders()){
            TreeNode tnChild = new DefaultTreeNode(child, realRoot);
            tnChild.setParent(realRoot);
            buildTreeRecursively(tnChild);
        }        
        return root;     
    }

    private void buildTreeRecursively(TreeNode currentNode){
        Folder folder =  (Folder)(currentNode.getData());
        for(Folder child : folder.getChildFolders()){
            TreeNode tnChild = new DefaultTreeNode(child, currentNode);
            tnChild.setParent(currentNode);

            buildTreeRecursively(tnChild);
        }
    }

    public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
        return selectedNode;
    }

    public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post **all** of your code. Only post the relevant parts, the irrelevant parts are affecting readability and don't help at all.

Comment: You're right of course. But I was searching a solution for so many days that I didn't know anymore what was relevant or not. Thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the exception to show up on page load. The dialog has an inputText which refers to `selectedNode`. That value is null on page load (because selection hasn't occurred yet), hence the `NullPointerException`. There are multiple solutions to your problem.

The easiest solution is setting `<p:dialog dynamic="true"` the dialog then accesses the property only when the dialog is accessed.

**Update:** You also need to update the dialog on select using an AJAX event handler.

```
<p:tree style="border:none;" id="folderTree" value="#{folderManagedBean.root}" var="folder" selectionMode="single" selection="#{folderManagedBean.selectedNode}">
    <p:ajax event="select" update="folderPanel"/>  
    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">  
        <h:outputText value="#{folder.name}" />  
    </p:treeNode>  
</p:tree>
```

The `update` attribute in the context menu needs to be removed.

Comment: I try to add dynamic="true". It works, but only the first time that the dialog is shown. The other times, it just keeps the previous value.

Comment: @CédricChristinaz you need to update the dialog after selection has occured. Look at PrimeFaces' update attribute ;-)

Comment: No, the exception is not shown on page load. The exception is shown when a click on a node of the tree.

Comment: I already use the update attribute in the context menu to update the dialog. Is it necessary to use it in another place?

Comment: @CédricChristinaz Yes, the current use of update will not work as the update gets triggered after the onComplete (correct me if I'm wrong). See my updated answer for how to update on select correctly ;-)

Comment: I try your solution and... its works! I agree with you, it's a better solution that the one I find. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @siebz0r Any advice on thi Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52678363/in-primefaces-tree-previous-selectednode-remains-highlighted-when-selected-on-a posted by me a couple of days ago? The selecetedNode doesn't get unhighlighted (yellow color doesn't go off) for the previously selectedNode when the xhtml page is seen in two clients (browsers). However, in the same client when a different node is selected in the tree it does work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solve it.
I add the attribute `appendToBody="true"` to the dialog and it works. The attribute `dynamic="true"` is not necessary.

**Update:** This solutions works, but is not so clear. I don't understand exactly what is the purpose of the attribute `appendToBody="true"`. That's why, the solution above is more correct, in my opinion.

Comment: I will not downvote as this seems a bit harsh, but don't use `appendToBody` for this. As the PrimeFaces manual states: `Use appendToBody with care as the page definition and html dom would be different, for
example if dialog is inside an h:form component and appendToBody is enabled, on the browser
dialog would be outside of form and may cause unexpected results. In this case, nest a form inside
a dialog.`. Instead see my answer which honestly may be your best solution.